# Java Image Quality (JPEG)

Tags: java, image, jpeg, pixel, dpi

Is it possible to get the current quality of an existing image?

I want to load a JPEG and save it again without any change in quality and DPI. (I need to do some pixel manipulation before saving)

Comment: See [JPEG: Lossless editing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Lossless_editing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPEG is a lossy format.

The direct way to do this, read the image, do what you need to do, reencode the image, will result in the image being slightly deteriorated.

That said, if that is fine, then you need to know that the way that quality works in JPEG encoding, is to determine how much information to keep about contrast.  The less quality, the less sharp a transition you can have.  In other words, this is not a single setting enclosed in the JPEG-file, but a setting determining the number of image data saved.

What you *can* do is to say that the final image need to be around the same size as the original.  You can then encode the result at different quality settings and choose the one giving the image size you want.